# On executing the function success or error of $.ajax() doesn't execute in sharepoint 2013. I am being using rest api

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint-2013

### Heading ##On execution of fetchCode function checkDuplicacy function doesn't execute

### Heading ##function fetchCode(){

```
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('FeedbackList')/items?$select=EmployeeCode";
        $.ajax({
            url : requestUri,
            type : "GET",
            async : "false",
            headers : {
                "accept" : "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success : checkDuplicacy,
            error : onError
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alert the error if you not familiar with developer tool debug(insert script into script editor webpart directly).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('car model')/items",
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            }
        })
            .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var count = data.d.results.length;
                alert(count);
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            })
            .always(function () {
                alert("complete");
            });
    </script>
```